# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)

Tags: java

The code below produces the following error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)`

Would one of you be able to help me find what could be causing the error? Where could be the issue?

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         
      Scanner cin=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the employee:");
      String name=cin.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter the age of the employee:");
      int age=cin.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter the salary of the employee:");
      Float sal=cin.nextFloat();
      System.out.println("Enter the year of joining of the employee(YYYY):");
      int doj=cin.nextInt();
      
      Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
      int year=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(now.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
      int joining=year - doj;
      System.out.println(joining);
      
      if(name.length()>=3&& name.length()<=20)
      {
          System.out.println("Name Valid");
      }
      else
      {
           System.out.println("Name Invalid");
      }
      
      if(age>=18 && age<=50)
      {
          System.out.println("Age Valid");
      }
      else
      {
           System.out.println("Age Invalid");
      }
      
      if(joining>25 || joining <0)
      {
          System.out.println("Valid Employee");
      }
      else
      {
           System.out.println("Invalid Employee");
      }
     }
}
```

I am attaching images to clarify the issue.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM6Sy.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6GOc.png)

Comment: Can you please tell us the requirements of the code snippets? What exactly do you want to implement? Do you get already an error message or unintended behaviour?

Comment: If you get a stacktrace, please include the entire stacktrace in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me:

```
Enter the name of the employee:
Fred
Enter the age of the employee:
20 1000 1968
Enter the salary of the employee:
Enter the year of joining of the employee(YYYY):
52
Name Valid
Age Valid
Valid Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and the image you have attached, you are expecting input from the user using the Scanner class. Provide the input in `STDIN` next to the `Source File` tab and your code should work.